# A sequence of differentiable functions that converge uniformly to a non differentiable function - is my example correct?

Tags: uniform-convergence

I was trying to find a series of differentiable functions that converge uniformly to a non differentiable function, to demonstrate the fact that uniform convergence doesn't imply anything about the differentiability of the function the sequence converges to.

I came up with this example -

$f_n(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
|x| &|x|\gt\frac 1 n \\
\frac x n &|x|\leq\frac1 n
\end{array}
\right. $

The sequence of functions converges uniformly to $|x|$, and all $f_n$ are differentiable, but $|x|$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$.

Does this seem right?

---

Edit- people here helped me understand that my functions are not continuous at $x=\frac 1n$, which I forgot to check.

So a correct example will be:

$f_n(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
|x| &|x|\gt\frac 1 n \\
\frac {nx^2}2+ \frac1{2n} &|x|\leq\frac1 n
\end{array}
\right. $

Which is continuous at $|x|=\frac1n$ and differentiable there.

Comment: What's $f_n(\frac1n)$? $\frac1n$ or $\frac1{n^2}$?

Comment: I assume you mean something likr $\frac n2x^2+\frac1{2n}$ for $|x|\le\frac1n$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus Sorry, fixed it

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen mmm... why does my example not work?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I thought it is enough that the function goes to zero when x approaches zero. Is it not?

Comment: The $f_n$ are discontinuous and therefore not differentiable at $\pm\frac1n$.

Comment: Oh, of course...
So now I understand. Thank you!

Comment: And what if I only had $f_n(x)=x$ when $|x|\leq\frac 1 n$?

Comment: @whyka still discontinuous at $x=-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I see. Okay, so Hagen's example is the correct one. Thanks all!

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you might also be interested in the [Weierstrass Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your functions are all discountinuous. I guess it is an overkill but 
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2^k \sin(2^k \cdot x)}{3^k}$$ 
will do a great job, as every $f_n$ is entire, but the limit is not real differentiable anywhere.

Comment: Does that not stand in contradiction to Weirstrass theorem? Stating that for a series of functions $f_n \in Hol(U)$ , $f_n \xrightarrow {u} f$, then $f$ is holomorphic and $f_n '  \xrightarrow {u} f'$ ?

Comment: @Ranc No because of holomorphic is only defined for open sets, indeed there is no open set, such that the $f_n$ converges uniformly, but they converge uniformly on the real axis

Answer (score 2):

Try:
$$
f_n\left(x\right) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}}
$$
They converge uniformly to $\vert x\vert$ and all of them are differentiable.